# Regex to match only the following strings

Tags: regex

I have a few strings and I need some help with constructing Regex to match them.

The example strings are:

```
AAPL10.XX1.XX2
AAA34CL
AAXL23.XLF2
AAPL
```

I have tried few expressions but couldn't achieve exact results. They are of the following:

```
[0-9A-Z]+\.?[0-9A-Z]$
[A-Z0-9]*\.?[^.]$
```

Following are some of the points which should be maintained:

1. The pattern should only contain capital letters and digits and no small letters are allowed.
2. The '.' in the middle of the text is optional. And the maximum number of times it can appear is only 2.
3. It should not have any special characters at the end.

Please ask me for any clarification.

Comment: Rule 1 and 2 are in contradiction. "special characters" is not a well-defined category. But rule 3 seems just a special case of rule 1. I mean, by rule one, there shouldn't be any "special characters" at the start either, so why a rule 3 is needed? Can a point occur at the start, at the end, in second position, ...? Can the first character be a digit? Can 2 points appear right after eachother? Is `.9.` a valid substring?

Comment: Hi Trincot, the points you mentioned make absolute sense.  The answers to you questions:
1. Can a point occur at the start, at the end, in second position, ...? (Ans) Point should not occur at end not at the front, but it can be present in the middle of the text.
2. Can the first character be a digit? (Ans) Yes, it can be a digit.
3. Can 2 points appear right after eachother? (Ans) No
4. Is .9. a valid substring? (Ans) No

Answer (score 2):

You can write the pattern as:

```
^[A-Z\d]+(?:\.[A-Z\d]+){0,2}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z\d]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z or a digit
- `(?:\.[A-Z\d]+){0,2}` Repeat 0 - 2 times a `.` and 1+ chars A-Z or a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CJ0XK5/1)